# How to prevent the upload of absolutely every type of file imaginable

Tags: php

Some time ago, someone injected javascript into my site.  Since then, I have added many more security features, including restrictions through htaccess, etc.  I would like to add an additional layer of security which is to prevent the uploading of absolutely every type of file imaginable through a php function.  I'm looking for something really simple, yet robust and came up with the following three possibilities.  This will need to apply site-wide on all pages and all posts.  Which one, if any, would work best.  Thank you

```
// Disallow all file uploads
if(filetype() != "jpgqstrhyzzstvm" && filesize > 0 ) {  //some random impossible file extension
   echo "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload any files.";
   $uploadOk = 0; 
}
```

OR

```
<input type="file" accept="none"></input>
   echo "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload any files.";
```

OR

````
function checkFileExtension($ext) {
    if ($ext == 'none') {
        $pass = (int)1;
    } 
    else {
        $pass = (int)0;
    }
    return (int)$pass;
}

$ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES['file']['name'], "."), 1);
$fileAccepted = checkFileExtension($ext);
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

if($fileAccepted==1 && $fileSize < '0'){
    echo "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload any files.";
}```
````

Comment: How do they upload the file?  Is it they can upload certain types and they also manage to upload malicious ones?

Comment: This does not make any sense at all. If you do not want people to be able to upload files to your system, then 1. do not offer a file upload and 2. do not process uploaded files. That's all.

Comment: @arkascha thank you to both for your comments.  I do not offer file uploads, but I think that I think that people or bots could find ways to upload malicious files if they want to.  I would just like to add an additional layer of defense by blocking this through a php function, if possible?

Comment: You cannot prevent something you have not a clue of how that might happen. A "layer of defense" is not something that exists outside of space and time, which magically heals every potential attack vector one might think of in future. A file upload is not possible without your code accepting and processing such file at the server side. If you don't do that, then things are fine. At least as long as you are talking about http based file uploads.